# How to send xml file data over ajax to Webmethod?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, webforms, webmethod

I am having an issue with sending XML over an ajax call to my Webmethod (C# Webforms):

I have tested the ajax call with JSON and I was able to send JSON to the Webmethod.

My response status code comes back 200 but it did not trigger the debugger on the webmethod when I try and send xml.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

JavaScript:

```
 var test = '<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body></note>';
                
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/App/drawIOjs/draw.aspx/GetDocument",
                    data: { xml: test }, 
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        debugger;
                        alert(msg);
                    },
                    failure: function (msg) {
                        // failure code here
                        debugger;
                        alert(msg);
                    }
                });
```

Webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]   
    public static string GetDocument(string test   ) 
    {
         string testing = test;       

        return "This string is from Code behind";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Several subtle problems in your code.

```
var strTest = "<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body></note>";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page-methods2.aspx/GetDocument",            // no slash at start
    data: JSON.stringify({ test: strTest }),          // need to stringify
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   // json
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        //debugger;
        alert(msg.d);                                 // get 'd'
    },
    failure: function(msg) {
        // failure code here
        //debugger;
        alert(msg);
    }
});

[WebMethod]
// returning a string, so don't need this.
    //[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]    
public static string GetDocument(string test)
{
    string testing = test;

    return testing; // "This string is from Code behind";
}
```